# Models for developing WCF applications

Tags: wcf, web-services, architecture, soa

Do you know any blueprints for organizing a WCF application in a way similar to Service Factory?

The problem is that although Service Factory is well organized, my application is a medium-sized one and it would be an overkill to use the factory - some of the sub-projects that the factory creates for me, I wouldn't ever use.

So what are the common models/architectures/blueprints/patterns for organizing the structure of a WCF application for a mid-sized project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article is great in terms of how to set up your project structure the right way:

http://code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0809101

Comment: +1 - excellent article. The "Assembly separation" section is really the core of it all - keep your various bits and pieces neatly organized in separate assemblies - makes your project a lot more manageable!